# What liability is there for a company whose genetic modifications make their way into originally non-modified crops?

Tags: damages, agriculture

Assume that a company has created genetically modified crop plant. A farmer purchases some seed from this company and plants this seed in his field. Somehow, that genetic modification [jumps species](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizontal_gene_transfer) and gets picked up by crops in neighbouring fields whose owners do not want this particular modification. Assume that this causes an injury-in-fact.

What liability would the company have to the injured owners?

Comment: "Jumps species"?

Comment: @user662852 That was my paraphrasing of the question author's original wording. Replace that with "somehow becomes incorporated into a species that didn't originally contain the modification". It is [a phrase that is used](http://www.greencareer.net.au/archived-news/antibiotic-resistance-jumps-species) to describe genetic spread between species.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe, but it is not an easy thing to do. See [MARSH v BAXTER [2014] WASC 187](http://www.supremecourt.wa.gov.au/_files/Judgment%20Summary%20-%20Marsh%20v%20Baxter%20(CIV%201561%20of%202012)%2028%20May%202014.pdf). To be successful the plaintiff would need to prove a failure to observe a duty of care (which would be difficult if regulations on GM crops had been followed) and some actual damage flowing from it.

Comment: But the manufacturer intentionally would be cross pollinating crops if their polin can get into other types of foods other than their own products.